# Change the full name of service reference in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, namespaces, service-reference

When I add a service reference to a project the full namespace of the service will be SolutionName.ProjectName.ServiceName. How can I change the full namespace to whatever I want, for example MyNamespace.ServiceName?

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can as that's .NET code, but what happens when you want to update your references?

You might get all of your changes overwritten.

Comment: Is there no way to tell visual studio to create my service reference with the namespace I want, and everytime I update the reference it stays with the same namespace?